# mDataProp DateTime format issue

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc-4

Hi I have a mDataProp `DateTime` formatting issue. Basically I want to display the date in one column and the time in another.

But as I understand it the mDataProp is directly related to your model, which does not have a time property just a adate......

Controller

```
var result = from a in data
                select new
                {
                    appointmentDate = a.AppointmentDate.ToShortDateString(),//.ToString("g"),
                    appointmentTime = a.AppointmentDate.ToLocalTime().ToString("t"),
                    appointmentName = a.AppointmentType.AppName,
                    appointmentID = a.AppointmentID
                };

//Return Json data for Datatable
return Json(new
{
    sEcho = param.sEcho,
    iTotalRecords = total,
    iTotalDisplayRecords = total,
    aaData = result
});
```

View

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        var urlRequest = $('#apptTable').data("request-url");
        var detailRequest = $('#apptTable').data("detail-url");

        $('#apptTable').dataTable({
            "bSort": false,
            "bServerSide": true,
            "sAjaxSource": urlRequest,
            "sServerMethod": "POST",
            "bProcessing": true,
            "bFilter": false,
            "aoColumns": [
                { "mDataProp": "appointmentDate" },
                { "mDataProp": "appointmentDate" },
                { "mDataProp": "appointmentName" },
                {
                    "mDataProp": "appointmentID",
                    "fnRender": function (oObj) {
                        return '<a href=\"' + detailRequest + '/' + oObj.aData.appointmentID + '\">Details</a>';
                    }
                }
            ]
        });
    });
</script>
```

I cannot create a second variable called `appointmentDate` in the controller, so I'll have to format in the view.

Any ideas?

Comment: I 'm having difficulty understanding what you are asking here. This solution looks like it would work if you change the second `"mDataProp": "appointmentDate"` to read `appointmentTime`. What is the problem?

Comment: no joy, the following error happens, DataTables warning (table id = 'apptTable'):Requested unknown pararmeter 'appointmentTime' from the data source for row 0    ...... I think it relates back to the model as it has no appointmenttime property, just appointmentDate ?

Comment: Basically can something like this be done....                         { "mDataProp": "appointmentDate", "format":"hh:mm" },

Comment: @Jon is right, I tested it and if I use `appointmentTime` it will work properly. It has nothing to do with the model, as `appointmentName` seems to work for you, I presume, and it's not part of the model. You are using a custom object for populating the table.

Comment: The model is too long to add here, but yes appointmentName is part of the model, you put in exactly as above and no error's return ?

Comment: After spending more time struggling, somehow after a clean and rebuild it finally functioned correctly, I wish I could provide a reason (other than a ghost in the machine), but thanks to all.